# CKEditor and Freemarker shows raw html

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, freemarker

I am trying to integrate CKeditor into JForum. 
I can write posts with CKEditor but when I show it to the visitors it shows raw html rather than rendering it accordingly.

I see this instead of the material which html and style is applied.

```
<h1>p> tags showing on frontend with ckeditor</h1> 

<div> 
<div><span style="font-family:myriad pro,trebuchet ms,arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px">Hi,</span><br /> 
<br /> 
<span style="font-family:myriad pro,trebuchet ms,arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px">I have installed CKeditor which does work fine on one page but on others when I submit my text it displays a <p> tag on the frontend of the website.</span><br /> 
<br />
```

I used

```
${post.text?html}
```

and it shows something like

```
 &lt;h1&gt;p&gt; tags showing on frontend with ckeditor&lt;/h1&gt; <br /> <br />
 &lt;div&gt; <br /> &lt;div&gt;&lt;span style="font-family:myriad pro,trebuchet 
ms,arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px"&gt;Hi,&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br /&gt; <br /> &lt;br /&gt;
 <br /> &lt;span style="font-family:myriad pro,trebuchet ms,arial,sans-serif; font-
size:16px"&gt;I have installed CKeditor which does
```

What config option should I tinker with to render the content correctly ?

**EDIT 1**
I made a helper class and a method like this.

```
str = str.replaceAll("&quot;","\"");
str = str.replaceAll("&lt;","<");
str = str.replaceAll("&gt;",">");
```

Now it works fine in the webpage but why does it work like this? 
I still don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Thats not surprising since `?html` is a builtin function for escaping html markup, you can read about it in the [documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_html).

If you dont want to esacpe html you should just use `${post.text}`